# Music Notes in Windows RT

Tags: c#, audio, windows-runtime, midi

I am trying to create a simple Piano App for Windows RT (Windows Store App).  I am a novice and I have been searching for code samples to send musical notes to PC speaker. I discovered that this was more difficult than I thought. 
I don't know C++ so I am trying to avoid using DirectSound/DirectMusic. 
I found this newly released MIDI API (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/dn643522.aspx) but I am not able to send MIDI Messages to Speaker. 
All I am looking for is a simple equivalent to Console.Beep in WinRT. Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: @Erno, it looks like you completely failed to comprehend the question.  Playing existing audio files and synthesizing tones are not the same thing.

Comment: @Emo: [It does.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/4fe3hdb1(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: @BenVoigt - I stand corrected. thanks!

Comment: @BenVoigt Console.Beep is not supported for WinRT. It is supported on the Win8/8.1 Desktop but not in WinRT. Can you please verify. Or am I missing something?

Comment: @SingularRiver: No, I think you're right.  I'm trying to prevent this question because people (1) think this is about playing a file and (2) think that's too trivial to have a question about it

Comment: Check out SharpDX. I think you can generate frequencies with the audio framework in it.

Answer (score 0):

Simulating an Analog Synthesizer in C++

[image]

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dn296556.aspx